Downloading more than 2000 objects from s3 into RDS directory
I am trying to download files from s3 into a directory (Oracle RDS).  I am made to understand that The download limit is 2000 files per procedure call for download_from_s3. If you need to download more than 2000 files from Amazon S3, split your download into separate actions, with no more than 2000 files per procedure call
Anyone have any ideas?  I am struggling righting the code
I've tried to modify the code but not sure how to make the split programmatically
`set serveroutput on format wrapped;
   DECLARE 
   V_TASKID VARCHAR2(100);
   V_LOGFILENAME VARCHAR2(100);
   V_CTR integer := 0;
   V_LOGS_CREATED integer := 0;
   V_CMD VARCHAR2(4000) := NULL;

   BEGIN
   -- DOWNLOAD
   SELECT rdsadmin.rdsadmin_s3_tasks.download_from_s3(p_bucket_name => 'test-bucket', p_directory_name => 'SF_FILES', p_s3_prefix =>  'test_folder/') INTO V_TASKID FROM DUAL;

   dbms_output.put_line('TASKID: ' || V_TASKID);

   V_LOGFILENAME:='dbtask-'|| V_TASKID ||'.log';

   WHILE V_LOGS_CREATED < 1
   LOOP 
   Select Count(1) 
   INTO V_LOGS_CREATED
   FROM TABLE(rdsadmin.rds_file_util.listdir(p_directory=>'SF_FILES')) where filename=V_LOGFILENAME;
   END LOOP;
   WHILE V_CTR = 0 LOOP
   V_CMD := 'SELECT count(*) FROM table(rdsadmin.rds_file_util.read_text_file(''test_dir'', ''dbtask-' || V_TASKID || '.log'')) WHERE text LIKE ''%finished successfully%''';
   execute immediate V_CMD INTO V_CTR;
   IF V_CTR > 0 THEN 
   dbms_output.put_line('The task finished successfully.');
   EXIT; 
   END IF;
   END LOOP;
   END;
   /`


